# QDialog not such file or directory - Qt Windows

Tags: windows, qt, qt-creator

I just installed Qt Creator 2.6.1 based on Qt 5.0.

I'm trying to open a project made on 4.8 but I can't compile it. It keeps showing me errors of "not such file or directory".

```
error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtGui/QApplication': No such file or directory 

error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QDialog': No such file or directory 

error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QMainWindow': No such file or directory 

error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QWidget': No such file or directory
```

And many more.

I added the qmake.exe path to PATH...do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 20):

Read the transition guides from `Qt4` to `Qt5`. [Link1](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Transition_from_Qt_4.x_to_Qt5) [Link2](http://www.kdab.com/porting-from-qt-4-to-qt-5/) [Link3](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/portingcppapp.html)

> One of the major internal infrastructural changes in Qt 5 compared to
>   Qt 4 is the splitting of widgets from the QtGui module into a new
>   QtWidgets module. This obviously will require buildsystem changes at
>   least, but also causes the need for downstreams to add includes for
>   headers which were not needed before, as those includes were removed
>   from headers which now remain in the QtGui module.
>
> Another includes-related issue in porting from Qt 4 to Qt 5 is dealing
>   with includes for classes which have moved to the QtWidgets module.
>   Whereas Qt 4 based code might use

```
#include <QtGui/QWidget>
This must be updated to either

#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>
Or more portably (Which works in Qt 4 and Qt 5):

#include <QWidget>
```

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem, made two changes

1. echo "QT += widgets" >> /fileProject.pro
2. add #include  QDialog  in the file containign QDialog declarations

previously including QtGui was enough but QT5 splits widgets into more .h files, thus making necessary to include them. For example QtMenuBar was included in QtMenu.h but now it requires QtMenuBar.h to be #included