# Qt c++ gui desktop app Phonon

Tags: qt, qt-creator, phonon

I am running on ubuntu 13.10 64bit with installed Qt Creator also i have installed libphonon-dev

my code looks like this:
mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <phonon/phonon> // yes directory /usr/include/phonon exists

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    Phonon::MediaObject *music = Phonon::createPlayer(Phonon::MusicCategory, Phonon::MediaSource("/home/erik/Downloads/Bob_Marley-No_Woman_No_Cry.mp3"));
    music->play();

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

I am getting 10 same errors:

```
 /usr/include/phonon/phonon:12: In file included from
 /usr/include/phonon/phonon:12:0,
 /home/erik/QtProjs/QtPlayer/mainwindow.cpp:3: from
 ../QtPlayer/mainwindow.cpp:3: /usr/include/phonon/effectwidget.h:28:
 error: QtGui/QWidget: No such file or directory  #include
 <QtGui/QWidget> ^ /usr/include/phonon/effectwidget.h
```

any other project file is default (mainwindow.h, mainwindow.ui, main.cpp)

Yesterday i have made a simple text editor(not from example), but i cant get through this error.

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14260985/2899350) question. It can be similar to your case if you're building a Qt 4 project with Qt 5.